# nullPointerException for set Alarm Manger in killed application

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, alarmmanager

I want to start my service via Alarm manager. i wrote below code. this code works good when my application to be in background or foreground but when i kill my application (I mean swiping application from recent apps) the program get an error. I don't know what is my problem and how can solve this.

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.company.test.helper.ServiceSchedular.startService(ServiceSchedular.java:74)
```

I have a class that extends from Application like below:

```
public class KITILApplication extends Application{

private static Context context;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    ACRA.init(this);
    ORMDroidApplication.initialize(this);
    KITILApplication.context=getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getappContext(){
    return KITILApplication.context;
}
}
```

and my ServiceSchedularService for scheduling alarms for starting service is in below:

```
public class ServiceSchedular {
     //Called from my main activity
     private ServiceSchedular() {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) KITILApplication.getappContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     }
     private static void startService(Date startDate) {
    uniqueIdForStart = (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    //PlEASE NOTICE: I checked my application via both of startintent(comment startIntent and startIntent)
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(KITILApplication.getappContext(), LocationService.class);
    //Intent startIntent = new Intent("com.company.test.START_SERVICE");
    PendingIntent startPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(KITILApplication.getappContext(), uniqueIdForStart, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //I get error from below line !! Line = 74
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millisToStartDate, startPendingIntent);
    stopService(startDate);
} 

 public static void checkNextPeriod() {
      .
       .
         startService(new Date(millisDate));
 }
 }
```

I have a broadcastReciever that called checkNextPeriod and in checkNextPeriod, i called startService method.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".Service.LocationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.company.test.START_SERVICE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I don't know my problem is for alarmManager object or intent object or application context or another thing. Please help me.

Comment: did you add **android:name=".KITILApplication** in manifest file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i add <application android:name=".KITILApplication"> this part in AndroidManifest.

Comment: Instead of KITILApplication.context=getApplicationContext();  try this: context = this;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 private ServiceSchedular() {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) KITILApplication.getappContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 }
```

Don't do this in a constructor. Just call `getSystemService()` when you need it.